# how to get an index of the elements not using setAttribute and getAttribute

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
const slider = document.querySelector('#image_slider');
const ul = document.querySelectorAll('#image_slider li img');

for(let i = 0; i < ul.length; i++) {
  ul[i].setAttribute('data-slide', i)
};

slider.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  if(e.target.nodeName === 'IMG') {
     console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-slide'));
  }


}, false);
```

My question is if there is other way to achive excatly the same without setAttribute and getAttribute?

Comment: store them somewhere?

Comment: Why exactly would you want that?

Comment: like `ul[i].dataset.slide = i`? or even simpler, setting a property `ul[i].slide = i`

Comment: thx guys for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can survive using dot notation. But dashes wouldn't work in dot notations, so you have to refactor your attribute names.

```
var element = document.getElementsById('image_slider');
element.mycustomattribute = 'foo';

console.log(element.mycustomattribute);

//output: foo
```

Be wary that attributes defined via the dot notation are not readable by the DOM.